# How to remove the keyword from the url using htaccess( Mod_rewrite)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

mywebsite url looks like below, in that I would like to remove the some of the keyword

http://mywebsite.comn/proto-type/awards/media-center/downloads

Need to be changed to

http://mywebsite.comn/proto-type/media-center/downloads

Please let me know how we can achieve this.

I tried with some of the Rewrite url which is not working.

Comment: Please post what you tried so far so we can help improve or make it work.

Comment: what http server you are using?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(proto-type)/((?!awards/).+)$ /$1/awards/$2 [L,NC]

Comment: we are using apache server, mod_rewrite module